# Remove /web/app_dev.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, symlink

## What i Have

- A Symfony2 project on DEV environment.
- My Symfony folder (named portfolio) is in this folder : `/home/araymond/public_html/portfolio`
- Let's say i have this url : http://www.example.com/~araymond/portfolio/web/app_dev.php/home

## What i want

Remove `/web/app_dev.php` from url.

## What have i tried so far

When i go to http://www.example.com/~araymond/portfolio/home, i encounter the following error:

```
No route found for "GET /~araymond/portfolio/home"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
```

Here is my portfolio/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~araymond/portfolio/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# DEV ENVIRONMENT #
RewriteRule ^$ web/app_dev.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app_dev.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is my portfolio/web/.htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I can't find any solutions that allow me to remove the `/web/app_dev.php` part.

Comment: @JesseBrands What do you mean? i don't want my website not being access at all, i want to change the url path from  http://www.domain.com/~araymond/portfolio/web/app_dev.php/home to  http://www.domain.com/~araymond/portfolio/home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there reason why you want to do this with .htaccess? You could just use symbolic link?
All you have to do is to rename that portfolio folder and create symbolic link that maps to web folder. Then in .htaccess change

```
 DirectoryIndex app.php
```

To

```
 DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
```

Then clear your cache : `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: hum, i am stranger to Symbolic links, can you provide a simple example? And also, since i got two defferent symfont project in my public_html folder, doesn't symbolic link will break the ability to acces th esecond one?

Comment: First rename that portfolio folder (ex. to symfony). Then go to public_html and write: `ln -s symfony/web/ portfolio` Syntax is: `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`

Comment: Worked, having somes troubles since i forgot to clear the cache, but i worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

does it work with **app.php**? if so just replace **app_dev.php** with **app.php**

Comment: Actually :  `http://www.domain.com/~araymond/portfolio/web/app_dev.php/home` does work, but i don"t want user to use this url, i want : `http://www.domain.com/~araymond/portfolio/home` as url, and i do not want to move to production environement